# How to get a cognito users' group (in AWS JS SDK V3)

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-sdk-js

I try to migrate from AWS JavbaScript SDK V2 to V3.

I want to retrieve the user groups a logged-in Cognito user (form an identity pool) belongs to.

In V2, this was as easy as looking in the ["accessToken"].payload['cognito:groups'] element of the sign-in response.

In V3 it's not part of the response. How do I get this piece of information in V3?

Answer (score 0):

I am using Amplify Auth, so I use the following code:

```
    const session = await Auth.currentSession();
    let idToken = session.getIdToken();
    console.log(idToken.payload["cognito:groups"]);
```

You should just switch to "idToken" instead of "accessToken" in the sign-in response, and that should do the trick.